# multiple polygons and multiple markers in Google MAPS API

Tags: google-maps

I am using google maps API for searching houses in a city(any location). In maps, by default markers will be loaded based on database results and user need to select locations they are interested. If user draws multiple polygons around markers, those markers should be visible and other markers should become invisible. I almost done most part of it.

Now the issue is,when i draw multiple polygons, only one marker with one polygon is visible. Other selected markers are getting invisible. I am trying from past two days and able to get it done. Can anyone guide me to fix this issue.

Mentioned issue is kept in jsfiddle, have a look and let me know

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hemachandra/bez82Lk1/16/

First select location and draw circles around multiple markers. then click on apply, you will find the issue!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: please add the code (and the link to the fiddle to your question itself)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add at the end of your drawFreeHand method: polygons.push(poly);

And change your isPointInside method as below.

```
function isPointInside(position){
    for(var i=0;i<polygons.length;i++)
    {
       if(google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(position, polygons[i]))
           return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

You were comparing with the same poly, that was the problem.

Comment: That's great. Let me know if you have further questions :D

Comment: how can i get "select area' button inside maps itself instead of outside??

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Shimmbo/bez82Lk1/18/ edited. Google map's api has a control for that: map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(button);